# MATLAB imageprocessing l*a*b colorspace. Marking custom colors

Tags: matlab, image-processing

I have a (matlab) image in `l*a*b` space. I would like to mark regions with specific `l`, `a` and `b` values. For example all regions with `l=80`, `a=50` and `b=90` should be marked and labelled as "C1"on the image. Similarly regions matching `l=40`, `a=70` and `b=80` should be marked and labelled as "C2"on the image. I am struck as there are around 10 colors I have to find and mark.

Any help please.

Comment: why can't you just write `newImg(l_channel==80 && a_channel==50 && b_channel==90)=C1`? where l_channel is the first channel in the Lab color space image.

Comment: If you are specific about the values that are assigned to the regions, for example, you may want a region to be labeled as 2, but it would be labeled as 8. All disjoint regions would still get different values. If this is okay, then you can just use put all 10 conditions separated by `OR` operator (use statement in the above comment with C1=1 and `newImg` initialized as a matrix of zeros) and then use `bwlabel`

Comment: Many thanks Parag. I tried to add in this way: 'code'orig=imread('mypic.jpg');
cform = makecform('srgb2lab');
c = applycform(orig,cform);
L = c(:,:,1);
A = c(:,:,2);
B = c(:,:,3);
newImg=(L==54 & A==65 & B==40);
imshow(newImg)'code' But it gives a dark image . I checked only one color and it exists on the image. Any help?

Comment: are you sure that the color exists in the L*a*b colorspace image i.e. in `c`? I tried this code and it works: `img=imread('peppers.png');
cform = makecform('srgb2lab');
c = applycform((img),cform);
L = c(:,:,1); A = c(:,:,2); B = c(:,:,3); newImg=(L==194 & A==155 & B==207);
imshow(newImg)`

You can run the code in MATLAB directly, `peppers.png` is a default image in MATLAB.

Comment: Also, read my second comment as: "If you are NOT specific..."

Comment: thank you so much. it perfectly works. actually i was using RGb values wrongly. thanks a lot for your effort in helping me. Have a nice day!